# How do I parse content with regular expression using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I am trying to use jQuery to break right ascension and declination data into their constituents (hours, minutes, and seconds) and (degrees, arc-minutes, and arc-seconds), respectively from a string and store them in variables as numbers.  For example:

```
$dec = "-35:48:00" -> $dec_d = -35, $dec_m = 48, $dec_s = 00
```

Actually, the data resides in a cell (with a particular class ('ra')) in a table.
At present, I have gotten this far:

```
var $dec = $(this).find(".ra").html();
```

This gives me the declination as a string but I cannot figure out how to parse that string. 
I figured out the regular expression `(-|)+\d+` (this gives me -35 from -35:48:00) to get the first part.  How do I use that in conjunction with my code above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var dec = '-35:48:00';
var parts = dec.split(':');
```

`parts[0]` would then be `-35`, `parts[1]` would be `48`, and `parts[2]` would be `00`

You could run them all through `parseInt(parts[x], 0)` if you want integers out of the strings:

```
var dec_d = parseInt(parts[0], 10);
var dec_m = parseInt(parts[1], 10);
var dec_s = parseInt(parts[2], 10);
```

I should point out this really has nothing to do with jQuery and is a Javascript problem (past getting the values out of the HTML document, at least) - The practice of prefixing a variable with a `$` is usually done to signify that the variable contains a jQuery collection. Since in this situation it contains HTML, it is a little misleading

Answer (score 1):

Use String.match()

```
$dec = "-35:48:00";
matches = $dec.match(/-*[0-9]+/g);
for (i=0;i<matches.length;i++){
  alert(matches[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tested this and it works as well, but the first solution suits my needs better. Too bad I cannot mark both answers as correct.